# Find index.html files & Rename with folder name and move file a level up

Tags: command-line, bash, sed

Little help in solving a workflow with shell script using the find command.

1. Finding all index.html files in every folder.

We can use this with find command for that.

```
find ./ -type f -name 'index.html'
```

1. Renaming the file index.html with the folder names.
2. After renaming the files, I wanted to move the files one level up.

I'm stuck at renaming and moving the files one level up.

As I have more than 1 lakh files, Xargs will be handy for this.

Here is code I have so far

```
find ./ -type f -name 'index.html' | xargs -P 4
```

```
├── dc
│   ├── adams-morgan
│   │   ├── car-donation
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   ├── feed.rss
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── junk-car
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   └── sitemap.xml
│   ├── american-university
│   │   ├── car-donation
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   ├── feed.rss
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── junk-car
│   │   │   └── index.html
│   │   └── sitemap.xml
```

Any help in in renaming the index.html files and moving the files one level up?

Thanks in advance 
Suresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `xargs` you can use `find -exec`. Inside, you can run a small `sh`-Script:

```bsh
find . -mindepth 2 -type f -name 'index.html' -exec sh -c '
    d="$(dirname "$1")";
    mv "$1" "$d/../$(basename "$d").html";
    rmdir "$d";
' find-sh {} \;
```

Comment: This works very well. In the root folder there is home page of index.html that is deleting too. 

As an alternative option, I did took the index.html as backup to keep it after code runs. 

Thanks Plumo for the fastest help :)

Comment: Add `-mindepth 2` so the file in the root is not touched

Comment: Hey Plumo, It works :) 

I just tested it on a new instance and it's spot on with your code. 

Thanks you so much mate.

Comment: Hi Pulmo, Can we able to remove .html extension for the final files? I did tried to remove .html in the final rename.. it isn't working. 

Should we try another code line for that functionality? 

thanks in advance :)